# Pulling a JSON object into donut chart using HighCharts

Tags: java, javascript, json, highcharts

I have JSON like this:

```
{
"count1": 72128,
"count2": 12377,
"count3": 72128,
"dataArray": {
    "ob1": {
        "prop1": 85
    },
    "ob2": {
        "prop2": 15
    },
    "ob3": [
        {
            "type": "x",
            "prop3": 7,
            "prop4": 48,
            "prop5": 69,
            "prop6": 82
        },
        {
            "type": "y",
            "prop3": 7,
            "prop4": 52,
            "prop5": 15,
            "prop6": 18
        }
    ]
},
"count4": 12377
}
```

I have been trying to use Highcharts to create a donut chart out of my data but can't figure out how to put it together. I have 2 main categories which are `ob1` and `ob2` each of which has the same two (name-wise) sub categories which are `type x` and `type y`.

How do I parse my JSON object and put it into the donut chart? I have been trying to follow the [highcharts example](http://jsfiddle.net/23Cr3/) but am having no luck.

**For clarification**

For more information about the total not adding up, I forgot to answer that: `ob1` and `ob2` Each have two sub properties `x` and `y` but `x` and `y` has two percentages / each. One is the percentage of the whole outer circle, and one is the sub-percentage of `ob1` and `ob2`. Also, my JSON object is stored in `http://json.html/` so I need to pull data from the properties there, which I am trying to figure out as well.

[image: Example]

Comment: Your data doesn't make any sense to me.  ob1 and ob2 are the inner circle (85% and 15%) and ob3 contains their sub-data?  I don't see sub categories x, y as part of ob1 and ob2.  Did you post incomplete JSON?

Comment: Their sub data is held in `ob3 `

Comment: so the `type: x` is the subdata for ob1 and `type: y` is subdata for ob2?

Comment: I've started to work on a solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/23Cr3/1/, but your first problem is that your subdata does not total it's parent...  You should also think about improving that JSON output, parsing it out in javascript is going to be kludgy.

Comment: @Mark thank you very much for the start, this is a lot of helpful information I can learn from and use!

Comment: @Mark for more information about the total not adding up, I forgot to answer that. `ob1` and `ob2` Each have two sub properties `x` and `y` but `x` and `y` has two percentages / each. One is the percentage of the whole outer circle, and one is the sub-percentage of `ob1` and `ob2`. I am editing my first post to add an example picture.